# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to return a list of cinemas from the MovieGlu API but I'm getting null pointer exception on line 98 of my code. The films return and I'm trying to get the Cinemas to return the same way. The API does return them in postman. I am using Retrofit2 to return data.

The Error when running the app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.retrofitapp.model.nearbycinemas.Cinema.getCinemas()' on a null object reference Retrofit
```

### MainActivity.class

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request()
                        .newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("api-version", "v200")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic *******************")
                        .addHeader("client", "WALS_1")
                        .addHeader("x-api-key", "**********************************")
                        .addHeader("device-datetime", "2018-09-14T08:30:17.360Z")
                        .addHeader("territory", "UK")
                        .addHeader("Geolocation", "****************;*************")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("https://api-gate2.movieglu.com/")
                .client(client.build())
                .build();

        MovieGluApi movieGluApi = retrofit.create(MovieGluApi.class);
        Call<Film> filmCall = movieGluApi.getFilmNames();
        filmCall.enqueue(new Callback<Film>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Film> call,Response<Film> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    Log.d("dfkjf", response.toString());
                    return;
                }

                assert response.body() != null;
                List<Film> films = response.body().getFilms();
                Log.d("dfkjf", response.toString());

                for (Film film : films){
                    String content = "";
                    content += "Film ID: " + film.getFilmId() +"\n";
                    content += "IMDB ID: " + film.getImdbId() +"\n";
                    content += "Film Name: " + film.getFilmName() +"\n\n";
                    Log.d("Film name", film.toString());
                    textViewResult.append(content);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Film> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        Call<Cinema> cinemaCall = movieGluApi.getNearbyCinema();
        cinemaCall.enqueue(new Callback<Cinema>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Cinema> call, Response<Cinema> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    Log.d("Response", "Message: " + response.toString());
                    return;
                }

                assert response.body() != null;
                List<Cinema> cinemas = response.body().getCinemas();
                Log.d("Response", "response: " + response.toString());
                for (Cinema cinema : cinemas){
                    String cinemaContent = "";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema Name: " + cinema.getCinemaName() +"\n";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema Address 1 " + cinema.getAddress() +"\n";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema Address: 2 " + cinema.getAddress2() +"\n\n";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema City: " + cinema.getCity() +"\n\n";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema Country " + cinema.getCounty() +"\n\n";
                    cinemaContent += "Cinema PostCode: " + cinema.getPostcode() +"\n\n";
                    textViewResult.append(cinemaContent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Cinema> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Line 98 Error

```java
List<Cinema> cinemas = response.body().getCinemas();
```

### cinemas.java (Model)

```java
public class Cinema {

    @SerializedName("cinema_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer cinemaId;
    @SerializedName("cinema_name")
    @Expose
    private String cinemaName;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("address2")
    @Expose
    private String address2;
    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("county")
    @Expose
    private String county;
    @SerializedName("postcode")
    @Expose
    private String postcode;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    @Expose
    private Double lat;
    @SerializedName("lng")
    @Expose
    private Double lng;
    @SerializedName("distance")
    @Expose
    private Double distance;
    @SerializedName("logo_url")
    @Expose
    private String logoUrl;

    List<Cinema> cinemas;

    public List<Cinema> getCinemas() {
        return cinemas;
    }

    public Integer getCinemaId() {
        return cinemaId;
    }

    public void setCinemaId(Integer cinemaId) {
        this.cinemaId = cinemaId;
    }

    public String getCinemaName() {
        return cinemaName;
    }

    public void setCinemaName(String cinemaName) {
        this.cinemaName = cinemaName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCounty() {
        return county;
    }

    public void setCounty(String county) {
        this.county = county;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(Double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(Double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public String getLogoUrl() {
        return logoUrl;
    }

    public void setLogoUrl(String logoUrl) {
        this.logoUrl = logoUrl;
    }
}
```

### MovieGluApi (Interface)

```java
public interface MovieGluApi {
    @GET("filmsNowShowing/")
    Call<Film> getFilmNames();

    @GET("cinemasNearby/")
    Call <Cinema> getNearbyCinema();
}
```

### Returned Data JSON

```java
{
    "cinemas": [
        {
            "cinema_id": 9461,
            "cinema_name": "Broadway Cinema - Nottingham",
            "address": "14-18 Broad Street",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "Nottingham",
            "county": "Nottinghamshire",
            "postcode": "NG1 3AL",
            "lat": 52.954319,
            "lng": -1.14397,
            "distance": 45.481624870276,
            "logo_url": "https://assets.movieglu.com/chain_logos/uk/UK-0-sq.jpg"
        },
        {
            "cinema_id": 41088,
            "cinema_name": "Regent Street Cinema",
            "address": "307 Regent Street",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "London",
            "county": "Greater London",
            "postcode": "W1B 2HW",
            "lat": 51.51683,
            "lng": -0.14277,
            "distance": 100.14079068585,
            "logo_url": "https://assets.movieglu.com/chain_logos/uk/UK-0-sq.jpg"
        },
        {
            "cinema_id": 9438,
            "cinema_name": "Scott Cinemas - The Atrium Cinema",
            "address": "Atrium Building",
            "address2": "King Street",
            "city": "East Grinstead",
            "county": "West Sussex",
            "postcode": "RH19 3DJ",
            "lat": 51.1264,
            "lng": -0.00885,
            "distance": 123.65933949165,
            "logo_url": "https://assets.movieglu.com/chain_logos/uk/UK-1198-sq.jpg"
        },
        {
            "cinema_id": 9000,
            "cinema_name": "Scott Cinemas - Radway Cinema",
            "address": "Radway Place",
            "address2": "",
            "city": "Sidmouth",
            "county": "Devon",
            "postcode": "EX10 8TL",
            "lat": 50.682831,
            "lng": -3.23856,
            "distance": 136.92054971699,
            "logo_url": "https://assets.movieglu.com/chain_logos/uk/UK-1198-sq.jpg"
        },
        {
            "cinema_id": 10355,
            "cinema_name": "New Carlton Cinema",
            "address": "Market Street",
            "address2": "Market Hall",
            "city": "Okehampton",
            "county": "Devon",
            "postcode": "EX20 1HN",
            "lat": 50.739399,
            "lng": -4.00368,
            "distance": 150.44700252827,
            "logo_url": "https://assets.movieglu.com/chain_logos/uk/UK-1262-sq.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "status": {
        "count": 5,
        "state": "OK",
        "method": "cinemasNearby",
        "message": null,
        "request_method": "GET",
        "version": "****",
        "territory": "UK",
        "device_datetime_sent": "2020-05-17T08:30:17.360Z",
        "device_datetime_used": "2020-05-17 08:30:17"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you forgot : 
@SerializedName("cinemas")
    @Expose
  List cinemas;

I hope it helps you.

Comment: i tried this ```@SerializedName("cinemas")
    @Expose
    List<Cinema> cinemas;

    public List<Cinema> getCinemas() {
        return cinemas;
    }```
but I still get the same error and I also tried it with this variable and the getters and setters for it
```List cinemas;```